# How to correctly merge two objects in blender

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I am trying to merge two close boxes into one single cuboid, from the GUI I am able to successfully create the two boxes and set a boolean modifier to the first box to unify(**UNION**) with the second box before deleting it.
But when I run the following script

```
import bpy
import ast

def delete(obj0):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj0.select = True
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

def Merge(obj0,obj1):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj0.select = True #selecting obj0 so the bpy modifier is constructed for it
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object = obj1
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].operation = 'UNION'
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Boolean")
    delete(obj1) #deleting obj1 since it's no longer needed
    return obj0 #returning obj0 which shoulda become the cuboid just incase a future need arises to merge with another box

def AddBox(x,y,z,width,height,depth):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(x, y, z))
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(width, height, depth))
    return bpy.context.active_object

#creating the two boxes and naming them
box0 = AddBox(0,0,0, .5,.5,.5)
box0.name='box0'
box1 = AddBox(0,1,0, .5,.5,.5)
box1.name='box1'

#merging them into a cuboid
Merge(box0,box1)
```

I get the following exception

`TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: BooleanModifier.object ID type does not support assignment to itself`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Need to set the active object.**

The issue here is that operators work on the `context.object` to set an object to "active state" use both

in 2.7x

```
context.scene.objects.active = ob0
ob0.select = True
```

in 2.80

```
context.view_layer.objects.active = ob0
ob0.select_set(True)
```

Then when you run an operator it sees `ob0` as context.

Just setting `ob0.select = True` is **not** *#selecting obj0 so the bpy modifier is constructed for it*

Without the above, because you added `ob1` last, it was still `context.object` and hence you were trying to set its union object to itself.

An object can be active but not selected, selected but not active.

Again from  a previous answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133292/15543 I showed how to add a modifier using api methods to get its reference IMO this is far simpler than using an operator.

Surely

```
bool = ob0.modifiers.new(name='booly', type='BOOLEAN')
bool.object = ob1
bool.operation = 'UNION'
```

is more readable (, and simpler) than

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj0
obj0.select = True 
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object = obj1
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].operation = 'UNION'
```

Soapbox TLDR:

Recommend getting out of the habit of always addressing via `bpy.context.foo.bar.blah`  For example in test code if the line `context = bpy.context` is added at the top, removes the need to use `bpy.context....` every bloody time, if later we choose to copy paste our code into operators or panels then the context matches the argument context  in draw and execute methods etc.

Or after adding modifier with operator

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')  
mod = obj0.modifiers[-1] # it's the last added
mod.object = obj1
mod.operation = 'UNION'
```

Here I've referred to the newly created modifier as a variable  "mod",  over `obj0.modifiers["Boolean"]` and definitely rather than the long winded `bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"]`

Comment: lol  @ "bloody".

Comment: thanks man... You are 2X a life saver. saved a drowning brother twice. really appreciate. I express my deepest **BATARANGS**