# 2.91 Python API No change after applying boolean modifier operator

Tags: python

How do I 'Apply' the Boolean *Difference* operation? I've written some Python that creates a hollow object visually, but in fact is not hollow. Visually I get the right thing:
[image]

Exporting to STL still has both objects (not an empty shell). I can manually complete the application of the Boolean operation by "Applying"
[image]

[image]

and deleting the inner object. Then the export to STL file is correct.

Here is the code I wrote, can someone let me know what calls I can make to apply the boolean modifier action and delete the object I used to cut into the other object with?

```
import sys
import bpy
D = bpy.data
C = bpy.context
from mathutils import *
import math
bpy.app.debug=True

########################################################################
# Stitch together vertices to create a face in the arc 
def face(column, row, columns, rows):
   v3 = ((column + 1) * rows) + row
   v3 = (((v3 // 4) * 4) + (v3 + 1) % 4)
   v4 = (column * rows + 1) + row
   v4a =  (((v4 // 4) * 4) + (v4) % 4)
   if v4a == v3:
      v4 = v4a - 4
   return (column* rows + row,
           (column + 1) * rows + row,
           v3,
           v4)

########################################################################
# Create an arc, start and eng angle, a scale to convert units, inner/outer size, height and the number of segments
def arc_segment(nme, start_ang, end_ang, scale, outer_size, inner_size, height, segs):
   # Assuming arguments are in centimeters and in degrees, adjust o meters and radians.
   # Change from degrees to radians
   start_ang = (math.tau / 360.0) * start_ang
   end_ang = (math.tau / 360.0) * end_ang
   if start_ang > end_ang:
      start_ang, end_ang = end_ang, start_ang

   # Change from meters (unit of measure in Blender) to centimeters
   outer_size = scale * outer_size
   inner_size = scale * inner_size

   # We're creating the arc, beginning with the newmericly smaller angle.
   if outer_size < inner_size:
      outer_size, inner_size = inner_size, outer_size

   # Arc will be created withe center at 0, 1/2 infront and 1/2 behing X/Y plane
   height = scale * height
   # Use z for "height", center is 0, so 1/2 height away (plus), and 1/2 height close (minus)
   p_height = (height * 0.5)
   m_height = (height * -0.5)

   # Think of the arc as a tube. This loop connects the faces to create the tube.
   verts = []
   for seg in range(0, segs + 1):
      verts.append((math.cos(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * inner_size,
                    math.sin(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * inner_size,    p_height))
      verts.append((math.cos(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * inner_size,
                    math.sin(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * inner_size,    m_height))
      verts.append((math.cos(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * outer_size,
                    math.sin(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * outer_size,    m_height))
      verts.append((math.cos(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * outer_size,
                    math.sin(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * outer_size,    p_height))

   sides = 4
   args = (segs, sides)
   faces = [face(x, y, segs, sides) for x in range(segs) for y in range(sides)]

   # Now cap the ends of the tube
   faces.append((0, 1, 2, 3))
   vbase = segs * sides
   faces.append((vbase + 3, vbase + 2, vbase + 1, vbase))

   # Create object, link it into the scene, make it 'active'.
   mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new(nme)  
   mesh_data.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)  
   mesh_data.update() # (calc_edges=True) not needed here  
   
   cube_object = bpy.data.objects.new(nme, mesh_data)  
   
   scene = bpy.context.scene    
   bpy.context.collection.objects.link(cube_object)
   cube_object.select_set(state=True)

########################################################################
# Solids modeling (CSG) take away coliding parts of one shape from another.
def csg(prim, cut, new_name, objects, operation):
   o_prim = objects[prim]
   o_cut = objects[cut]
   cut_work = o_prim.modifiers.new(type="BOOLEAN", name=new_name)
   cut_work.object = o_cut
   cut_work.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
   o_cut.hide_set(True)                 # Hidden--But will still exist in an STL export.
   # --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
   # What calls do I add here to "apply" the "difference" and delete the o_cut object?

   # --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
   
########################################################################
#
objects = bpy.data.objects
set_scale = 2.54 * 2
#
# Create some arcs
arc_segment("big_display_hull", 5.0, 90.0, set_scale, 11.5, 8.0, 4.5, 34)
arc_segment("big_hollow_hull", 6.5, 88.5, set_scale, 11.6, 7.7, 4.1, 34)

csg("big_display_hull", "big_hollow_hull", "o1", objects, 'DIFFERENCE')

arc_segment("attach_hulls",        360 + 110, 360 - 110.0, set_scale, 9.0, 8.0, 4.9, 120)
arc_segment("attach_hollow_hulls", 360 + 113, 360 - 113.0, set_scale, 9.2, 7.9, 4.1, 120)
csg("attach_hulls", "attach_hollow_hulls", "o3", objects, 'DIFFERENCE')

arc_segment("small_display_hull", 360 - 10, 360 - 65, set_scale, 11.5, 8.0, 4.5, 22)
arc_segment("small_hollow_hull", 360 - 11.5, 360 - 63.5, set_scale, 11.6, 7.7, 4.1, 22)
csg("small_display_hull", "small_hollow_hull", "o3", objects, 'DIFFERENCE')
```

I did try a suggested solution [Scripting:How to correctly add a boolean modifer to an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133291/scriptinghow-to-correctly-add-a-boolean-modifer-to-an-object) , after fixing a "'apply_as' unrecognized" issue, it ran. However I see that the boolean is still not applied. Given that blender 2.90.1 is so different than v 2.79, can someone post a complete python Boolean (CSG) example where the resulting meshes are the 'finished' objects? -- Also, I saw that 2.91 (beta) has something called 'exact solver', could someone post similar code to use the "exact solver"?

Comment: Hi and welcome! I think that's well explained in the linked answer. If you run into other issues, just let us know.

Comment: Tried the referenced, but after fixing "'apply_as' unrecognized" issue, I see that the boolean is still not applied. given that 2.90.1 is so different, can someone post a complete python Boolean (CSG) example where the model only has the 'finished' objects?
-
Also, I saw that 2.91 (beta) has something called 'exact solver', could someone post the code to use the "exact solver"?

Comment: Very borderline, have re-opened and answered.  Main issue was assigning an active object for the operator.

Answer (score 3):

**Turn on developer extras / use autocomplete in the console.**

- Please use 4 space indent (not 3).
- As noted the apply modifier no longer has an "apply_as" property.
- For the exact solver set the `solver` attribute to exact, which is
  the default value anyway. Turn on developer extras in user prefs to get a tooltip displaying this, or use auto-complete in the console.

  ```
   >>> C.object.modifiers['o1']
   bpy.data.objects['big_display_hull'].modifiers["o1"]

   >>> C.object.modifiers['o1'].solver
   'EXACT'

   >>> C.object.modifiers['o1'].solver = 'FOO'
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "FOO" not found in ('FAST', 'EXACT')
  ```
- Operators work on the active and selected object(s). Have overridden
  the operator such that the active object is the prim. Can set the active object with `context.view_layer.objects.active = ob` (You were only selecting)
- The apply modifier operator will fail silently, test run active object has no modifiers

  ```
   >>> bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply()
   {'CANCELLED'}
  ```
- Remove any object with `bpy.data.objects.remove(ob)` *This has been well documented and answered here*

Changes for 2.91 using exact solver. *There is no need to set as it is the default when modifier added*

```
def csg(prim, cut, new_name, objects, operation):
   o_prim = objects[prim]
   o_cut = objects[cut]
   cut_work = o_prim.modifiers.new(type="BOOLEAN", name=new_name)
   cut_work.object = o_cut
   cut_work.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
   o_cut.hide_set(True)                 # Hidden--But will still exist in an STL export.
   # --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --
   # What calls do I add here to "apply" the "difference" and delete the o_cut object?
   #cut_work.solver = 'EXACT' # it's the default anyhow.
   bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(
      {"object" : o_prim},
      modifier=cut_work.name,
      )
   # --  -
```

Result of running with changes above.

[image]
*High orange area is z-fighting between "big display hull" and "attach hulls"*

Comment: I'd love to know how to apply a collection to the modifier, now that's a thing in 2.92

Comment: I found out. operand_type="COLLECTION"

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

The main goal is now solved: an STL file that looks the same as in Blender.  The corrected code is below.

- The Boolean DIFFERENCE modifier runs successfully--Apparently it can "quietly" fail. <Any insight on getting more info on this?>
- Once an object is used to cut away "material", the code deletes it successfully now.
- Code now uses the implication that a modifier is created "as a child" of the currently active object

````
import sys
import bpy

D = bpy.data
C = bpy.context
from mathutils import *
import math

bpy.app.debug = True

########################################################################
# Stitch together vertices to create a face in the arc
def face(column, row, columns, rows):
    v3 = ((column + 1) * rows) + row
    v3 = ((v3 // 4) * 4) + (v3 + 1) % 4
    v4 = (column * rows + 1) + row
    v4a = ((v4 // 4) * 4) + (v4) % 4
    if v4a == v3:
        v4 = v4a - 4
    return (column * rows + row, (column + 1) * rows + row, v3, v4)


########################################################################
# Create an arc, start and eng angle, a scale to convert units, inner/outer size, height and the number of segments
def arc_segment(nme, start_ang, end_ang, scale, outer_size, inner_size, height, segs):
    # Assuming arguments are in centimeters and in degrees, adjust o meters and radians.
    # Change from degrees to radians
    start_ang = (math.tau / 360.0) * start_ang
    end_ang = (math.tau / 360.0) * end_ang
    if start_ang > end_ang:
        start_ang, end_ang = end_ang, start_ang

    # Change from meters (unit of measure in Blender) to centimeters
    outer_size = scale * outer_size
    inner_size = scale * inner_size

    # We're creating the arc, beginning with the newmericly smaller angle.
    if outer_size < inner_size:
        outer_size, inner_size = inner_size, outer_size

    # Arc will be created withe center at 0, 1/2 infront and 1/2 behing X/Y plane
    height = scale * height
    # Use z for "height", center is 0, so 1/2 height away (plus), and 1/2 height close (minus)
    p_height = height * 0.5
    m_height = height * -0.5

    # Think of the arc as a tube. This loop connects the faces to create the tube.
    verts = []
    for seg in range(0, segs + 1):
        verts.append(
            (
                math.cos(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * inner_size,
                math.sin(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * inner_size,
                p_height,
            )
        )
        verts.append(
            (
                math.cos(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * inner_size,
                math.sin(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * inner_size,
                m_height,
            )
        )
        verts.append(
            (
                math.cos(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * outer_size,
                math.sin(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * outer_size,
                m_height,
            )
        )
        verts.append(
            (
                math.cos(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * outer_size,
                math.sin(start_ang + (end_ang - start_ang) * (seg / segs)) * outer_size,
                p_height,
            )
        )

    sides = 4
    args = (segs, sides)
    faces = [face(x, y, segs, sides) for x in range(segs) for y in range(sides)]

    # Now cap the ends of the tube
    faces.append((0, 1, 2, 3))
    vbase = segs * sides
    faces.append((vbase + 3, vbase + 2, vbase + 1, vbase))

    # Create object, link it into the scene, make it 'active'.
    mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new(nme)
    mesh_data.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
    mesh_data.update()  # (calc_edges=True) not needed here

    cube_object = bpy.data.objects.new(nme, mesh_data)

    scene = bpy.context.scene
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(cube_object)
    cube_object.select_set(state=True)


########################################################################
# Solids modeling (CSG) take away coliding parts of one shape from another.
# The main corrections (the "answer") are in this method here:
#
def csg(prim, cut, new_name, objects, operation):
    o_prim = objects[prim]
    o_cut = objects[cut]
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = o_prim   #Setting the primary object as active.
    cut_work = o_prim.modifiers.new(type="BOOLEAN", name=new_name)
    cut_work.object = o_cut
    cut_work.operation = "DIFFERENCE"
    o_cut.hide_set(True)  # Hidden--But will still exist in an STL export.
    rs = bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply({"object": cut_work.object}, modifier=cut_work.name)
    print(rs)   # If this quietly fails, this prints {'CANCELLED'}. How can one know what to fix? Maybe logs or something that can be looked at to find out why?


########################################################################
#
objects = bpy.data.objects
set_scale = 2.54 * 2
#
# Create some arcs
arc_segment("big_display_hull", 5.0, 90.0, set_scale, 11.5, 8.0, 4.5, 34)
arc_segment("big_hollow_hull", 6.5, 88.5, set_scale, 11.6, 7.7, 4.1, 34)

csg("big_display_hull", "big_hollow_hull", "o1", objects, "DIFFERENCE")

arc_segment("attach_hulls", 360 + 110, 360 - 110.0, set_scale, 9.0, 8.0, 4.9, 120)
arc_segment(
    "attach_hollow_hulls", 360 + 113, 360 - 113.0, set_scale, 9.2, 7.9, 4.1, 120
)
csg("attach_hulls", "attach_hollow_hulls", "o2", objects, "DIFFERENCE")

arc_segment("small_display_hull", 360 - 10, 360 - 65, set_scale, 11.5, 8.0, 4.5, 22)
arc_segment("small_hollow_hull", 360 - 11.5, 360 - 63.5, set_scale, 11.6, 7.7, 4.1, 22)
csg("small_display_hull", "small_hollow_hull", "o3", objects, "DIFFERENCE")

```
````

Comment: Thanks to all who helped me connect the dots :-)